# Having trouble running pygame script on raspberry pi zero on 3.5" screen

Tags: python, linux, pygame, raspberry-pi, pi

Im trying to run my test game-script written in pygame on my raspberry pi zero w on a 3.5" LCD screen (which is working).

But I keep getting this error. And I haven't after ALOT of hours found a fix for this, does anyone know how to fix this?
Im running the latest version of Raspberry Pi OS lite

````
Script:

import pygame

pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode()

x = 50
y = 50
width = 40
height = 60
velocity = 10

run = True 
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(100)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False


    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        x -= velocity

    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        x += velocity

    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        y -= velocity

    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        y += velocity



    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (x, y, width, height))
    pygame.display.update()


pygame.quit()```






Error Message:
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.14, Python 3.9.2)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
The path /dev/dri/ cannot be opened or is not available
The path /dev/dri/ cannot be opened or is not available
The path /dev/dri/ cannot be opened or is not available
The path /dev/dri/ cannot be opened or is not available
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/srv/Game/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    win = pygame.display.set_mode()
pygame.error: No available video device
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to include your params in win = pygame.display.set_mode()
like this:
win = pygame.display.set_mode(size=(x,y), width=width, etc...)

You will need to declare those variables before win = pygame.display.set_mode()

Are you executing from terminal or IDE?
Do you have one or more displays?

Comment: Hello.  I've tried changing pygame.display.set_mode() as you suggested (also chekced the documentation), but with no success.  I did declare them before the function. I have tried executing the python file through SSH and one the rpi itself, and I only have one display.